# PHPExcel_Reader_HTML produces empty file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I try to use `phpexcel` library to convert the simplest html table to excel, but to no avail. Now, I do it like this:

```
require_once ('/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
file_put_contents('tmp.html','<table border="1"><tr><td>123</td></tr></table>');
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML;
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('tmp.html');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("myExcelFile.xlsx");
```

When I finally open `myExcelFile.xlsx`, I see it is empty, whereas `tmp.html` is not.
I use `PHPExcel_1.8.0` version of the library.

**EDIT**

Thanks to Mark, it is now working. However, I see, that somewhat difficult html is not rendered correctly. Like this table header, for example:

```
<Table style="border-collapse: collapse;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4"><THead><TR><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="5" >1</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="5" >2</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="5" >3</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC "  colspan="7"  rowspan="1" >4</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="5" >16</TH></TR><TR><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC "  rowspan="1" >5</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="4" >7</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC "  colspan="5"  rowspan="1" >8</TH></TR><TR><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="3" >6</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="3" >9</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="3" >10</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC "  colspan="3"  rowspan="1" >11</TH></TR><TR><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC "  colspan="2"  rowspan="1" >12</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px "  rowspan="2" >15</TH></TR><TR><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px " >13</TH><TH style="background-color:#F8F8F8; border:1px solid #CCCCCC ; width:100px " >14</TH></TR></THead></Table>
```

Comment: And you get absolutely no errors of any kind?

Comment: Odd..... I actually get a warning message: "Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "tmp.html" in /Projects/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/PHPExcel_1.8.0/Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/HTML.php on line 427"

Comment: Well, I was wrong. I made it show warnings and see this one: `DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Funny how I sometimes get problems appearing here the day after they've been logged on the github issues log:

Edit line 427 of `Classes/PHPExcel/Reader/HTML.php`, which reads

```
$loaded = $dom->loadHTMLFile($pFilename, PHPExcel_Settings::getLibXmlLoaderOptions());
```

and change it to

```
$loaded = $dom->loadHTMLFile($pFilename);
```

Comment: Thank you, Mark. I will check it in a second and report back the results.